# Show scroll from multiple Div on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three div on my screen i.e. I divided my screen into three parts by placing three div, like three columns. When I scroll, complete page gets scrolled now. But I want to scroll only that div on which mouse is being hovered. How can I do it?

Comment: The answer is complicated and depends on what you're trying to do.  I would suggest you read up on how height and width propagate from parent to child, and how to use the overflow property.

If you post a jsfiddle/plunkr we might be able to help more specifically.

Comment: Set a max height for each div and add `overflow-x: scroll ` in CSS for each div

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `overflow: auto`;

See:https://jsfiddle.net/j6vLdayu/

Answer (score 0):

Even `overflow-y: scroll` would do. Just set a height or max heidht for each div and add `overflow-y: scroll` in CSS for each div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vishl/gyqu8/